# IIB9 Message Flow Unable To Reconnect To SQL Server After Database Restart

Tags: messagebroker

I am using `IIB 9.0.0.2`, in which I have created a message flow which is connecting to the SQL server Database (version 2012) to insert records in the tables.
The code is written to interact with DB every 1 min.

In case when the Database goes down, the broker is throwing the below error (which is as expected), but when the db comes up, it still throws the same error, instead of connecting back, until I restart the flow.

> Root SQL exception -1 /opt/ibm/IE02/2.0.1/lib/libodbcinterface.so
>   Child SQL exception 16006 6005 [unixODBC][IBM][ODBC SQL Server Legacy
>   Driver][SQL Server]SHUTDOWN is in progress.[/b] [13:35] 
>   opt/ibm/IE02/2.0.1/lib/libodbcinterface.so Child SQL exception 20119
>   [unixODBC][IBM][ODBC SQL Server Legacy Driver]20119[/b]

Please suggest any configuration which I have to do at the flow/connection manager/server level to make the flow reconnect back after SQL server DB restart.

Answer (score 0):

IIB 9.0.0.2 uses DataDirect SQL Server Wire Protocol. I suggest you try to set parameters **Connection Retry Count** and **Connection Retry Delay**. More information there:

http://media.datadirect.com/download/docs/odbc/allodbc/help.html#page/odbc/connection-option-descriptions-for-sql-server-wi.html#